# LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file

Tags: java, eclipse, cygwin, unix-ar

i'm doing an augemented reality program. i was handed this project and im new to cygwin and android programming. i have to use cygwin to compile one of my cpp file. however when i do a ndk-build on cygwin this error comes out:

```
$ ndk-build
Android NDK: ERROR:/cygdrive/c/project/jni/Android.mk:QCAR-prebuilt: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file   
Android NDK: Check that /cygdrive/c/project/jni//../../../build/lib/armeabi/libQCAR.so exists  or that its path is correct
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:43: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

and this are my android.mk codes:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := QCAR-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /../../../build/lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libQCAR.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../build/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := ImageTargets
# The TARGET_PLATFORM defines the targetted Android Platform API level
TARGET_PLATFORM := android-5
# This variable determines the OpenGL ES API version to use:
# If set to true, OpenGL ES 1.1 is used, otherwise OpenGL ES 2.0.
USE_OPENGL_ES_1_1 := false
# Set OpenGL ES version-specific settings.
ifeq ($(USE_OPENGL_ES_1_1), true)
    OPENGLES_LIB  := -lGLESv1_CM
    OPENGLES_DEF  := -DUSE_OPENGL_ES_1_1
else
    OPENGLES_LIB  := -lGLESv2
    OPENGLES_DEF  := -DUSE_OPENGL_ES_2_0
endif

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wno-write-strings $(OPENGLES_DEF)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := \
    -llog $(OPENGLES_LIB)



LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := QCAR-prebuilt

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ImageTargets.cpp SampleUtils.cpp Texture.cpp

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)**
```

I'm not a pro at programming so i would like some guidance.

Comment: out of interest how did you solve your problem

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Please write the solution in the "Answers" section and accept it.

Comment: Hi CtheW Can you please tell us how did you solve your problem?

Comment: Please post the way u solved the issue

Answer (score 11):

Had same problem, tried multiple paths but dint work. Finally solved it problem by simply copying the sample project in the Development\Android\vuforia-sdk-android-2-0-30\samples folder and then executing ndk-build through cygwin. Hope that helps :-)

Comment: +1. In `samples` folder there is `Readme.txt` file with text `Please download the sample apps at https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps and unpack them in this folder`.

Comment: The solution might have worked for this case but not even closely related to the problem described above :(

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, default `Android.mk` presumes that the `ImageTargets` folder is located at `../vuforia-sdk-android-x-x-xx/samples/ImageTargets-x-x-x`, but after I had downloaded the samples and extracted them to the samples directory, the location was the following: `../vuforia-sdk-android-x-x-xx/samples/vuforia-sampleapps-android-x-x-xx/ImageTargets-x-x-x`. So it turned out that there was an additional subdirectory and this is why the build failed. To make it work I edited the `Android.mk` as follows:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /../../../build/lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libQCAR.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../build/include
```

should be changed to

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = /../../../../build/lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libQCAR.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../build/include
```

, where the additional set of `/..` takes care of that additional subfolder. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

step 1 : copy sample into C:\Development\Android\vuforia-sdk-android-2-0-31\samples

step 2 :  open command prompt

write commnad  1 :  cd C:\Development\Android\vuforia-sdk-android-2-0-31\samples\ImageTargets-2-0-7

write commnad  2  : ndk-build

step 3 : import project into eclipses

step 4  : https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-3-compiling-running-vuforia-sample-app

so build successfully. Don't forgot to set path of ndk in Environment Variables.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem, I put the variable `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` as r9, while it had to be either 4.8 or 4.4. I changed it to 4.8 and it worked.

PS: Checking if the missing file actually exists or not will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just contributing to the list of working solutions, just in case all the above did not work.

In my case, it turned out that there was a **space** in my path. Cygwin does not like spaces in paths very much. Removing the spaces in my path fixed the issue.

As a tip, you may wish to have your working directory in a path like `C:\projects\MyNativeProject` and your Android SDK and NDK on paths without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add my 2c, just in case it helps out some poor soul. In my case, the ndk did not like the leading back slash. i.e. changing from

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := /foo/foo.so
```

to

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo/foo.so
```

solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

use relative dir path works on Mac:

```
-LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/$(ARCH_PATH)/lib.so
+LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./lib/$(ARCH_PATH)/lib.so
```