# Windows 7 Eclipse Indigo Android NDK error LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file

Tags: android-ndk, eclipse-indigo

I have setup android ndk and tested it using the samples in the ndk folder.

I think my error is something to-do with the paths but I am not sure how to fix it. I think my problem is similar to this question [LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419093/local-src-files-points-to-a-missing-file) but there is no solution given and therefore my question is not a duplicate.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)



include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := QCAR-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = ../../../build/lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libQCAR.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../build/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------



include $(CLEAR_VARS)



LOCAL_MODULE := ImageTargets

# The TARGET_PLATFORM defines the targetted Android Platform API level

TARGET_PLATFORM := android-5

# This variable determines the OpenGL ES API version to use:
# If set to true, OpenGL ES 1.1 is used, otherwise OpenGL ES 2.0.

USE_OPENGL_ES_1_1 := false

# Set OpenGL ES version-specific settings.

ifeq ($(USE_OPENGL_ES_1_1), true)
    OPENGLES_LIB  := -lGLESv1_CM
    OPENGLES_DEF  := -DUSE_OPENGL_ES_1_1
else
    OPENGLES_LIB  := -lGLESv2
    OPENGLES_DEF  := -DUSE_OPENGL_ES_2_0
endif



LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wno-write-strings $(OPENGLES_DEF)



LOCAL_LDLIBS := \
    -llog $(OPENGLES_LIB)



LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := QCAR-prebuilt

.

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ImageTargets.cpp SampleUtils.cpp Texture.cpp



LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm



include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Hi alex I have the exactly same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419093/local-src-files-points-to-a-missing-file.
If you have found solution for your problem please post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the answer to a similar problem here: [ndk build library outside main project source tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551951/ndk-build-library-outside-main-project-source-tree/12553884#12553884)

Note also that when you specify LOCAL_SRC_FILES, NDK will look for them **relative to LOCAL_PATH** (i.e. where your Android.mk lives).

Finally, with ndk-r8b on Windows it is easier to avoid cygwin and use **ndk-build.cmd** and not open **bash**